# If $\frac{n^2}{3} < xy \leq n^2 - 5$, then does it follow that $n > \max(x,y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

My question here is pretty basic:

> If $\frac{n^2}{3} < xy \leq n^2 - 5$, then does it follow that $n > \max(x,y)$?

Here, $n, x, y$ are positive integers.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $n, x, y$ be positive integers such that
$$\frac{n^2}{3} < xy \leq n^2 - 5.$$

Suppose to the contrary that we have
$$n \leq \max(x,y) = \frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2}.$$

We get the bounds
$$\frac{n^2}{3x} < y \leq \frac{n^2 - 5}{x}$$
which implies that
$$\frac{5 - n^2}{x} \leq -y < -\frac{n^2}{3x}.$$

It follows that
$$n \leq \frac{\bigg(x + \dfrac{n^2 - 5}{x}\bigg) + |x - \dfrac{n^2}{3x}|}{2}.$$

I then asked WolframAlpha to solve the last inequality [for $x$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+a+%3C%3D+%28%28x+%2B+%28%28a%5E2+-+5%29%2Fx%29%29+%2B+%7Cx+-+%28a%5E2+%2F+3x%29%7C%29%2F2+for+x) and then [for $n=a$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+a+%3C%3D+%28%28x+%2B+%28%28a%5E2+-+5%29%2Fx%29%29+%2B+%7Cx+-+%28a%5E2+%2F+3x%29%7C%29%2F2+for+a), but I am not sure I can interpret the outputs by myself, as they are a bit messy.

Can anybody help?  Thanks!

Comment: Let $xy=75,n=9$.  This appears to be a counterexample...

Comment: Thank you for those counterexamples, @abiessu, and @Gribouillis!  I had expected the conjecture to fail for small $n$.  Could you also check for $n$ large, say greater than ${10}^6$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every $n\ge 3$, a counter example is given by $x=n-2$ and $y=n+1$
indeed in that case we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{n^2}{3}< n^2 - n - 2 = x y \le n^2 - 5
\end{equation}

Comment: I apologize for being unclear - so it follows that $n \leq \max(x,y)$ is **FALSE**, and therefore, that $n > \max(x,y)$ is **TRUE**, is that what you are saying, @Gribouillis?

Comment: How is this a counterexample, @Gribouillis?  It satisfies the constraints of the problem under consideration.

Comment: I updated the answer with a real counterexample. Sorry for this.

Comment: Thank you for your update, @Gribouillis!  =)